The specified instance type r8g.medium is not valid
When trying to deploy EB instance type r8g.medium in us-east-2, get error

Updating Auto Scaling launch configuration named: awseb-e-sh8msjpgjp-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingLaunchConfiguration-rk4dt1gQ09xZ failed Reason: Resource handler returned message: "The specified instance type r8g.medium is not valid (Service: AutoScaling, Status Code: 400

Works fine with r7g.medium, and docs say r8g should be available in this region.

Can you check the specific availability of r8g.medium in the us-east-2 region using the AWS CLI:
aws ec2 describe-instance-type-offerings --location-type region --filters Name=instance-type,Values=r8g.medium --region us-east-2

Some EC2 types are not supported in some AZs
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/ts-as-instancelaunchfailure.html#ts-as-instancelaunchfailure-6

Im running this command to see availability zones:  aws ec2 describe-instance-type-offerings --location-type availability-zone --filters Name=instance-type,Values=r8g.medium --region us-east-2
and it shows that its available in us-east-2a, which my eb environment is in. But im still getting the error.

Are you using a specific placement group for your EC2 ?

I'm using Elastic Beanstalk, I can't figure out how to do that
